# How to create and load new helper in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

i want to create new function in helper, but it still failed : 
`Call to undefined function`

i save my helper at `app/Helper/Text_helper.php` using `namespace App\Helpers;`
and load helpers on BaseController using `protected $helpers = ['text'];`

Reference : https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/helpers.html#extending-helpers
but it's still not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not mentioned in documents but remember to add a suffix **_helper** to filename of your helper otherwise it will not work in codeigniter 4.

For example if you have created a helper **xxx.php**, change it to **xxx_helper.php**.

To load a helper you can use **helper** function (Like: `helper('xxx.php');`) or add it to **$helpers** array that is an protected property in **BaseController**

Answer (score 1):

If your idea is to "extend" (replace) a function on the **stystem/helpers/text_helper** note the lowercase in the name of the file, you have to respect it.

Also, the helper doesn't need a namespace... the helper loader will search for it.

> The helper() method will scan through all PSR-4 namespaces defined in app/Config/Autoload.php and load in ALL matching helpers of the same name. This allows any module’s helpers to be loaded, as well as any helpers you’ve created specifically for this application. The load order is as follows:
>
> 1. app/Helpers - Files loaded here are always loaded first.
> 2. {namespace}/Helpers - All namespaces are looped through in the order they are defined.
> 3. system/Helpers - The base file is loaded last

the namespace will be used to load a helper on other location, for example:

```
helper('Libraries\MyFunctions');
```

> as long as that path can be found through a namespace that has been set up within the PSR-4

---

Reference:
https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/helpers.html#extending-helpers

Answer (score 1):

***Tested in CodeIgniter Version: 4.4.3***

**Step-1:**

Create a Helper named `"custom_helper.php"` in the `"App\Helpers"` Directory.

**Step-2:**

Open `"App\Config\Autoload.php"` and the Created Helper name by removing `"_helper.php"` in this file.

```
public $helpers = [
        'custom', // Helper Name: custom_helper.php
    ];
```

File: custom_helper.php

```
<?php
function hello(){
   echo "Hello Function";
}
?>
```

**Step-3:**
All Done! Now we can call our function  `Example: hello()` from controller using the function name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the helper into the app/Config/Autoload.php and still not work then please try to run composer dump-autoload

Comment: With this solution your problem is solved or still you facing the issue?

Comment: thanks, its done just remove `namespace App\Helpers;` at `app/Helper/Text_helper.php`